# Link File to two locations in mercurial

Tags: file, mercurial, shared, tortoisehg

I'm new to Mercurial and am trying to figure out how to "Link" a file between two locations.  By this I mean if I have a file in one folder in the repository and then check that file in it will show the file out of date in anther folder and when I "sync" or do a "get" it will refresh the file in the second location.   I'm moving up from an old VSS repository and in VSS this was a "Shared" file.

I am using TortoiseHg v2.8 on a windows platform.

Thanks

dbl

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**

You can't have shared files in Mercurial

**Longer answer**

You can try to use OS-specific linking of files (if client's and repo's hosts uses  the same OS)

**Long, tricky way**

- If file can be moved into separate directory, you can use subrepositories (file in dir will be separate repository, two target locations - subrepositories in superrepo)
- **At the rights of delirium!!! UNTESTED** You can try to place file in Subversion repo (1.7+) and create in the same Subversion repository file-based externals for linked file. With hgsubversion you can have Subversion-repo linked to your base repo